# How do I connect to a local Rails back-end via a React Native app running on Expo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I've inherited a fairly complex React Native app, so apologies in advance if I don't know everything I should know about the app as I ask this question.

I have a React Native app that uses Expo. I run `expo start` to start up Metro in the browser. I then use the LAN option to connect my iPhone to the local app via the Expo app on my phone. When I use LAN, I connect to the local app on my computer via an IP address that looks like `192.168.0.xxx:19000`.

The app loads fine on my phone, but whenever I attempt a network request (i.e., a `fetch` call to the Rails server also running on my local machine), the app can't seem to connect to the back-end.

I am running the Rails server with the following command: `rails server`

Once the Rails server is running, I can go to `127.0.0.1:3000` in my browser to see the back-end of the app created in Rails.

However, whenever I make a `fetch` request from the app to the API at either `127.0.0.1:3000` or `192.168.0.xxx:19000` (the `xxx` is an actual three-digit number), the request fails. Basically, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make a proper request from the React Native app running on my phone via Expo to the Rails server running on my local machine.

I have tried things like `http` vs. `https`, but no luck. I've also Googled the heck out of this, and I still can't figure out what's going on. Part of the problem is that the app itself is so large and complex and I'm still so new to it that I'm not sure if I'm just fundamentally misunderstanding how Expo and React Native are supposed to make requests to a back-end, or if the app itself has something quirky in it that's preventing me from making requests.

Any advice/ideas on how I can potentially get the app to properly connect to the Rails server would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't access the local app from the internet.  For example, if I start running an app locally and ask you to view `127.0.0.1:3000` you won't be able to see what is on my local machine, that's why it is local.  So, if I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to do something you just can't.  Both apps need to be accessible by internet traffic to be accessed in the way you are describing, again,  if I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, Rockwell Rice. If I connect my physical phone to the app running on my local machine via Expo and the LAN option in Metro Bundler (i.e., `192.168.0.xxx`), when I make a `fetch` request in the app code, what is possible? Can I access `localhost` from the React Native app code if I have a server running on `localhost`? Do I have to use `192.168.0.xxx` to make a request to the local server because the request is actually coming from my phone and the phone accesses my machine via `192.168.0.xxx`? This is where I'm confused, I think. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot access localhost from the internet, that is why it is local.  So the app you are running locally needs to be deployed and hosted somewhere in order for you to access it online.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but that being the case, I can't really develop locally, which doesn't make sense. There must be a way to develop locally so that I can make changes and get instant feedback to those changes. Are you suggesting that the back-end API the app uses be hosted somewhere, and my local version of the React Native code make requests to that hosted back-end API so that I can still develop the React Native part locally, but it can make requests to a properly hosted API so that network requests don't fail? Point being, what's the best way to set this up for local dev? Thank you.

Comment: You need to run the react app locally in order to have it access the local backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either run the react app locally as well in order to have it access the local backend, or change the port of the localhost application to make it accessible to the internet.

As you stated, running something like

```
$ rails server -b 0.0.0.0
```

Will allow you to access it.

Comment: By that rationale, if I were to make my Rails back-end available on the network via a `192.168.0.xxx` address, then that should also work, right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you'll have to try it

Comment: No biggie. I can't delete the answer for you either. Anyway, I'm going to try making the Rails server available on the network and will report back. If it works, you can amend your answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: I think I finally solved the problem as per your advice Rockwell Rice. I ran the Rails server using `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`, which made it available on the network via `192.168.0.xxx`. After doing that, I changed the URL the React Native app was hitting up from `127.0.0.1` to `192.168.0.xxx`, and it finally established a connection with the Rails server. Thanks again. If you want to amend your answer, I can mark it as correct. Thanks.